# What is the consequences of a software in multiple PPA?

Tags: package-management, ppa

Say a software exist in version A in PPA X and in version B in PPA Y. Version A is newer than version B. What will be the behaviour of synaptic/apt if both PPA are added to apt?

Will there be conflict between version A and B, or will apt simply install version A?

Comment: It should install the higher version only.

Comment: So that means that it is safe to add two repositories containing the software?

Comment: It does not make any sense to add two PPAs.

Comment: PPA X contains the most recent version of package `m` and a few related dependencies, but nothing else. PPA Y contains package `n`, which I need, but also an older version of package  `m`. If I cannot find a PPA with the most recent version of both package, I'm afraid I have to add both PPA X and Y.

Comment: You can install all needed packages without adding any PPA. You can download and install packages manually.

Comment: But will a manually installed package be automatically updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A newer version will be installed.

A conflict may happen if the dependencies are conflicting.